# Set jpeg_quality for certain post-types

Tags: images

Without using timthumb, does anyone know of a way to set jpeg_quality for certain post-types or posts?

Comment: Do it by custom image sizes:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74103/set-jpeg-compression-for-specific-custom-image-sizes

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the [jpeg_quality filter](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/jpeg_quality) and do a check for the post type you want to apply the filter to.

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'my_jpeq_quality' );
function my_jpeg_quality( $quality ) { 
if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'your_post_type') || (isset($post_type) && $post_type == 'your_post_type')) :

return 100;  //Set quality here

endif;

 }
```

Comment: hmmm... this code works, however all images that aren't 'your_post_type' are now being generated with extremely low quality. (a 444k image is now 4k!) I tried adding an "else return 90" but this seems to get ignored... 
`
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'my_jpeq_quality' );
function my_jpeg_quality( $quality ) { 
if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'work') || (isset($post_type) && $post_type == 'work')) {

return 100;  //Set quality 

}else return 90;

 }

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'wpse_39179_jpeg_quality_for_post_type' );

function wpse_39179_jpeg_quality_for_post_type( $quality ) {

    if ( ( isset($_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'post_type_slug' ) || ( isset( $post_type ) && $post_type == 'post_type_slug' ) ){

        // For this post type, we want 100% quality
        return '100';

    }else{

        // Otherwise, revert back to what was passed into this filter to allow us to modify it elsewhere
        return $quality;

    }

}/* wpse_39179_jpeg_quality_for_post_type() */
```