# Set JPEG compression for specific custom image sizes

Tags: functions, filters, images, compression

I use various custom image sizes (by `add_image_size`) and I have set my JPEG compression to 30% with this filter:

```
function jpeg_quality_callback($arg) {
   return (int)30;
}
add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'jpeg_quality_callback');
```

If I am not mistaken, the above code compresses **all** of my custom image sizes with 30%. Now, for two of my custom image sizes named `splash1` and `splash2`, I want to set the compression to 80%. How is this possible?

Or alternatively, exclude those image sizes from the 30% compression filter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `'jpeg_quality'` filter hook functions accept two arguments: `$jpeg_quality` and `$function` which is the function from within the filter hook is fired and can be either `image_resize` or `wp_crop_image`. So there is no way to selectively set the quality of `.jpeg` images according to image size from this filter hook function.

However, you still can hook to a later action hook in the process of uploading attachments and adjust the `.jpeg` image quality of uploaded images at that point according to thier specific size to suit your needs. First set the `jpeg_quality` to the maximum to preserve the original image quality, then hook to `added_post_meta` action hook (which is fired at the end of inserting attachment metadata`) to adjust the quality, as follow:

```
// set the quality to maximum
add_filter('jpeg_quality', create_function('$quality', 'return 100;'));

add_action('added_post_meta', 'ad_update_jpeg_quality', 10, 4);

function ad_update_jpeg_quality($meta_id, $attach_id, $meta_key, $attach_meta) {

    if ($meta_key == '_wp_attachment_metadata') {

        $post = get_post($attach_id);

        if ($post->post_mime_type == 'image/jpeg' && is_array($attach_meta['sizes'])) {

            $pathinfo = pathinfo($attach_meta['file']);
            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' . $pathinfo['dirname'];

            foreach ($attach_meta['sizes'] as $size => $value) {

                $image = $dir . '/' . $value['file'];
                $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

                if ($size == 'spalsh') {
                    // set the jpeg quality for 'spalsh' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 100);
                } elseif ($size == 'spalsh1') {
                    // set the jpeg quality for the 'splash1' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 30);
                } else {
                    // set the jpeg quality for the rest of sizes
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 10);
                }

                // or you can skip a paticular image size
                // and set the quality for the rest:
                // if ($size == 'splash') continue;

                imagedestroy($resource);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will affect the newly uploaded images only. If you want to update the quality of previously uploaded images, you can utilize `register_activation_hook` of plugins. Create a new php file in `wp-content/plugins` directory and name it whatever you like (`update-jpeg-quality.php` for example) and add the following code to it:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Update JPEG Quality
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74103/set-jpeg-compression-for-specific-custom-image-sizes
Description: This plugin will change the jpeg image quality according to its size.
Author: Ahmad M
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12961/ahmad-m
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ad_modify_jpeg_quality');

function ad_modify_jpeg_quality() {

    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));

    if (empty($attachments)) return;

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        $attach_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment->ID);
        if (!is_array($attach_meta['sizes'])) break;

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($attach_meta['file']);
        $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' . $pathinfo['dirname'];

        foreach ($attach_meta['sizes'] as $size => $value) {

            $image = $dir . '/' . $value['file'];
            $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

            if ($size == 'spalsh') {
                // set the jpeg quality for 'spalsh' size
                imagejpeg($resource, $image, 100);
            } elseif ($size == 'spalsh1') {
                // set the jpeg quality for the 'splash1' size
                imagejpeg($resource, $image, 30);
            } else {
                // set the jpeg quality for the rest of sizes
                imagejpeg($resource, $image, 10);
            }

            imagedestroy($resource);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now visit your Plugins page and hit `activate` of the `Update JPEG Quality` plugin. This will loop through all your previously uploaded `.jpeg` images and adjust their quality according to the values and conditions you specify in the plugin. Then you can safely deactivate and delete this plugin. *Please test on testing environment first before applying to production site*.

Comment: This is a very interesting reply. How do I add both 'splash1' and 'splash2' to the IF statement?: **if ($size == 'splash')...**

Comment: +1 Great Answer! You could use the Question link as *Plugin URI* and your profile as *Author URI*...

Comment: @AmandaDuke: You can extend the `if` statement by `elseif`. See my update.

Comment: @brasofilo: Thanks for the advice, just updated accordingly.

Comment: The *"share"* link just bellow the question provides a short url that contains your user id. That's useful for [some](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer) [badges](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist) ;)

Comment: Outstanding answer Ahmad. I tested it and it works fine (although didn't test the plugin as I do not need to change old images). Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @Ahmad there is a bug in your code. When uploading an image, if it is smaller than the dimensions of the smallest custom image size, then this error appears: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. So basically, when no custom image is made, the error appears. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @AmandaDuke Thanks for pointing that out. This error happen because `$attach_meta['sizes']` is expected to be an array while in this case it is not. In most cases it should and this can only happen if we dont have custom image sizes _and_ we don't specify the default image sizes in **Settings -> Media Settings**. To be safe and make sure we have an array we can add a check before passing it to the `foreach` loop: `if (is_array($attach_meta['sizes']))`. Please see the updated code.

Comment: @AhmadM Thank you very much for detailing the solution. Works perfectly.

Comment: @AhmadM Ah I noticed that you updated the plugin, but not the code you have above the plugin - which is the one that I was using. Is there any chance that you can update that one too?

Comment: @AmandaDuke: Both blocks of code have been updated. The first block was before: `if ( $post->post_mime_type == 'image/jpeg' )` and now it is `if ( $post->post_mime_type == 'image/jpeg' && is_array($attach_meta['sizes']) )`

Comment: Excellent, works very well. I was going with this *dummy* solution prior to your fix: `foreach ( (array) $attach_meta['sizes'] as $size => $value) {` Thanks again for the very quick support!